# CakePlugin::load('Facebook'); is not loading

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.6 and first I have included the cakephp Facebook plugin at
`app/config/facebook.php` ? Tell me if any other file to include.
and secondly i have included Facebook sdk at `app/vender/faceboo-php-sdk/`... ?
But It gives 2 errors like :

> Error: The application is trying to load a file from the Facebook
>   plugin

and second is :

> Error: Make sure your plugin Facebook is in the app\Plugin directory
>   and was loaded

And I have imported files in app controller and get the login url like this.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    App::import('Vendor', 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0/src/facebook');
    $this->Facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'     =>  'app_id',
        'secret'    =>  'secret_id'

    ));
    $this->set('fb_login_url', $this->Facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri' => Router::url(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'), true))));
    $this->set('user', $this->Auth->user());

    $this->Auth->allow('login', 'register');
}
```

Please help me i'm new to this ?

Comment: I started writing an answer but `I have included the cakephp Facebook plugin at app/config/facebook.php` That's not a plugin. _are_ you using a plugin (if so which one) or just trying to use the sdk files directly?

Answer (score 0):

> As this is a not a plugin please remove CakePlugin::load('Facebook');

Below are the steps to be followed to integrate Facebook SDK on your cakephp application:-

Download the facebook SDK and place it in `app/Vendor` directory from [facebook github page](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/).
Then include following lines in your controller:-

```
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR','../Vendor/fb/src/Facebook/');
require_once("../Vendor/fb/src/Facebook/autoload.php");
use Facebook\FacebookClient;
```

Make sure your directory structure for your facebook app is:-

> reputation/app/Vendor/fb/src/Facebook